# Opinions vs. Hypotheses backed by facts

Tags: discussion

I think there is a disconnect in terms of what constitutes an opinion in the context of the humanities, which is understandable on a tech forum.

Unlike most of mathematics and physics, where proofs are and hypotheses are validated in a functional manner, such exacting standards are not possible with the humanities.  Rather, scholars research material, generate insights, and try to support those insights backed by citation of source material, to a degree that it passes peer review.  (i.e. We can't know for certain what an author thought once they are dead, only speculate and hypothesize.)

My recent question on the categorization of "Robot" myths was an attempt to utilize the genre expertise of Stack to find support for or valid arguments against my hypothesis, which is an attempt by a mythologist to bring clarity to the persistent myth of our time, which involves technology, and is distinct in the post-computing era.

I'm not going to talk about bias or preference of moderators, who are, after all human, but only comment that I've already gotten valuable responses in the comments on my question, even though it is closed.

I think I've been a decent contributor to Stack in several areas where I have knowledge, and it's disappointing that I can't utilize that same function of Stack to get answers for my own, necessarily more complex questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is (in this post, not the earlier question that your post refers to).

Comment: [Link to the relevant question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151185/31394). Also, since you mention "moderators", can I just note that until this moment, no SFF moderator has had any interaction with your question. It was closed by community members just like yourself. (It was edited by a [movies.se] moderator, but he's just an ordinary user here with no special powers - his edit even had to be approved by other users before taking effect.)

Comment: (Neither did any moderators close the previous iteration of that question.)

Comment: Duke, unfortunately this site does not really have much consistency in regards to close question, actually, I should re-word that to say it consistent of being inconsistent with closed questions. As it only takes 5 people to mark one closed, it happens quite often. Unfortunately there is no up or down vote for closing questions as this would invariably make for a more balanced system.

Comment: @KyloRen - Yes, but it also only takes 5 votes to get a question *reopened*. And if enough people disagree with the original close vote, the question stays open.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem/s with your question...

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151185/can-all-robot-films-and-shows-be-divided-into-two-main-categories

...is that it's overly broad and any answers it generated will be little more than the opinions of individual users, leading to discussion and counter-discussion without necessarily having any **clear and definitive answer**.

What are our options? - *Yes, they can be categorised thusly* (cue discussions about why this answer is wrong) or *No, they can't be categorised thusly* (cue discussions about why this answer is wrong). Either way, the answers that are generated will be little more than chit-chat about what individual users think about your hypothesis. That's why we frown upon questions that are opinion based and overly broad.

Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> .. there is no actual problem to be solved: ***“I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”***

Comment: Clear definitive answers are only possible for a subset of the type of questions popular on this sub-site, as with Film & Television and many other Humanities sub-forums.  I've gotten similarly structured questions through on numerous occasions, leading me to believe opposition to this question was based on a combination of personal affront per the premise, and objection to my choices of the category names, which run counter to many peoples personal affinities.

Comment: @DukeZhou - The category names are irrelevant. The core of the objection is that you're asking people if they agree with you or not. That's not something this site does well.

Comment: I stated in the question I wanted answers backed up by examples and confirming either the validity or invalidity of the question. Whether people agree or disagree is irrelevant--it's all about whether they can support their answer in a similar fashion to how I support the valid premise of the question.

Comment: @DukeZhou - It is not irrelevant. Per the main tour "*Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are **likely to generate discussion rather than answers.***". Demanding examples doesn't absolve you of the requirement to post questions that are objectively answerable.